# R-4.0.1 Rtools not available

Tags: rtools

Recently started working in R 4.0.1 When installing packages I encounter the following

````
```WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/USER/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/dplyr_1.0.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1294122 bytes (1.2 MB)
downloaded 1.2 MB
````

When trying to install the Rtools package i encounter the following:

````
  package ‘Rtools’ is not available (for R version 4.0.1)```
````

Comment: Download Rtools and install https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/